# FlashBuilder ASP.NET Development Server not installed

Tags: asp.net, eclipse, flash, flash-builder

This annoying error appears when I try to Import an existing project (from the code repository) into the workspace.  It prevents the IDE from even letting me view the source code, let alone compile it.  I don't need ASP.NET to compile to a /bin/ folder, let alone view code with color syntax highlighting just to help a junior, and I don't wish to install a bunch of stuff just to do so.

How to erase this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file .flexProperties in the project root.

Remove any mention of aspNet, and **change flexServerType** from 32 or whatever **to 0**.